# CSS bootstrap: how do I keep side by side div keep content height equals on resize?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing a problem with a kind of vertical slider I've been working on. The problem is that, when I change the display resolution, thumbnails at rigth don't have the same height than the picture at left. It's kinda difficult to explain by writing, so I've made a codepen to help me understand it better.
So it is:

https://codepen.io/fmalmeida/pen/ZOOagX

```css
.container2 {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container1 {
  background-color: magenta;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 609px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.lSection {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 609px;
}
.rSection {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 609px;
}
.lSection>* {
  min-width: 100%;
  /*   min-height: 609px; */
}
.rSection>ul {
  max-height: 609px;
}
.rSection>ul img {
  max-height: 150px;
}
li {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container2 row-fluid">
  <div class="container1 span10">
    <div class="lSection span9">
      <img class="contain" src="http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/58122377.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="rSection span3">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>
            <img src="http://cdn.olhares.pt/client/files/foto/big/330/3301699.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <img src="http://cdn.olhares.pt/client/files/foto/big/330/3301699.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <img src="http://cdn.olhares.pt/client/files/foto/big/330/3301699.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <img src="http://cdn.olhares.pt/client/files/foto/big/330/3301699.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To test, you only need to resize your browser window. In higher resolutions it seems well, since I've defined a maximum height. When you resize window to a lower resolution you'll see my problem happen.

Could anyone please, give me a tip on how do I resize both main image and thumbnails, at the same time and same height?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I achieved this with another approach, using viewport size calculation. So in this approach, I defined a 2:3 format, for images, calculating it's height based on this format and in the viewport units I want(calculated more or less to follow bootstrap2 gridsystem width calculations.)

Here is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/fmalmeida/pen/WxxJvG

```css
.imageFormatDiv {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  height: calc((2/3)*62.55vw);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 62.55vw;
}

.imageFormatDiv2 {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  height: calc((2/3)*15.4vw);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 15.4vw;
}

.imageFormatDiv img,
.imageFormatDiv2 img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.rSection {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.rSection ul {
  margin: 0px;
}

/* .rSection li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
} */

.rSection li:nth-child(1),
.rSection li:nth-child(2),
.rSection li:nth-child(3) {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .imageFormatDiv {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
  }
  .imageFormatDiv2 {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
  }
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container2 row-fluid">
  <div class="container1 span10" style="background-color:red">
    <div class="lSection span9" style="background-color:blue">
      <!--       <img class="contain" src="http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/58122377.jpg"> -->
      <div class="imageFormatDiv">
        <img class="singleImage" src="https://placemaker.moredata.pt/documents/22267/23267/1-1-A.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rSection span3 hidden-phone" style="background-color:orange">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="imageFormatDiv2">
            <a><img src="https://placemaker.moredata.pt/documents/22267/23267/1-1-A.jpg"></a>
            <div class="pWrapper">
              <p>TESTE 123</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="imageFormatDiv2">
            <a><img src="https://placemaker.moredata.pt/documents/22267/23267/1-2-3.jpg"></a>
            <div class="pWrapper">
              <p>TESTE 123</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="imageFormatDiv2">
            <a><img src="https://placemaker.moredata.pt/documents/22267/23267/1-4-F.jpg"></a>
            <div class="pWrapper">
              <p>TESTE 123</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="imageFormatDiv2">
            <a><img src="https://placemaker.moredata.pt/documents/22267/23267/1-3-D.jpg"></a>
            <div class="pWrapper">
              <p>TESTE 123</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using bootstrap version 2.

If you'd look at the examples they [provide](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html), you can see this is expected behaviour. Resize their website, and you see the containers that are `span1`-`span11` jump to full width.

Instead, I'd recommend you to upgrade Bootstrap, or create your own implementation for mobile websites.

Layout table:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Label</th>
                <th>Layout width</th>
                <th>Column width</th>
                <th>Gutter width</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Large display</td>
                <td>1200px and up</td>
                <td>70px</td>
                <td>30px</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Default</td>
                <td>980px and up</td>
                <td>60px</td>
                <td>20px</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Portrait tablets</td>
                <td>768px and above</td>
                <td>42px</td>
                <td>20px</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Phones to tablets</td>
                <td>767px and below</td>
                <td class="muted" colspan="2">Fluid columns, no fixed widths</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Phones</td>
                <td>480px and below</td>
                <td class="muted" colspan="2">Fluid columns, no fixed widths</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: I didn't really get what you mean. But I did it in another way. Stil needs to be  improved, but it pretty close to what I need. I'll had a codepen in the answer.